# Asymptotic value of a Cauchy Singular integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, asymptotics, cauchy-principal-value, singular-integrals

Let,

$\zeta(x,t) = A_0sin(k_0x)cos(\omega t) + \frac{2k_0A_0}{\pi} \{\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{cos(kx)cos(\beta t)-cos(k_0x)cos(\omega t)}{k^2-k_0^2}dk\}$

Here $\beta ^2 = gktanh(kh)\ and\  \omega^2 = gk_0tanh(k_0h)$ where $g,h$ are given constants as well as $k_0$. $x$ can be treated as a spatial coordinate while $t$ as time coordinate. As such $x$ & $t$ can be viewed as parameters both greater than $0$.

I need to prove that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \zeta(x,t) = A_0cos(k_0x-\omega t)$. However, I think the answer must come out as $A_0sin(k_0x-wt)$

As such, one knows that the solution is dominated by $k_0$ ,thus one can expand the integrand about $k_0$. However, the problem is the denominator i.e. $(k^2-k_0^2)$ makes the integrand become singular at $k_0$.

The problem is one of the transient analysis of a wavemaker given [here](http://iwwwfb.org/Abstracts/iwwwfb09/iwwwfb09_12.pdf).

Comment: I appreciate anyone's effort to help solve this

Answer (score 0):

Hint: In the integral add and subtract $\sin(kx)\sin(\beta t)$ and $\sin(k_0 x)\sin(\omega t)$

Comment: I'm still having trouble. It replaces an unknown integral with another unknown one